Error when trying to set Key for custom component
Using React with Typescript I am trying to do the simple thing, that is iterate through a collection of object and based on each of those - create an instance of custom component.
Given that I'm using map function, i do get the index so I'm using this as key.
Problem: getting a red squigly when setting key with message:

Type '{ imageSource: string; target: string; title: string; hasGap:
boolean | undefined; key: number; }' is not assignable to type
'IntrinsicAttributes & { hasGap?: boolean | undefined; imageSource:
string; title: string; target: string; disabled?: boolean | undefined;
} & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'key' does not exist on
type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { hasGap?: boolean | undefined;
imageSource: string; title: string; target: string; disabled?: boolean
| undefined; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

Now in my understanding, key property should exist by default on every React component so I do not understand where's that error coming from...
Example of a simple component, not even using map:
const MissingKeyComponent = () => {
  return(
    <div>Key cannot be passed when creating this component</div>
  )
}

<MissingKeyComponent key={100}></MissingKeyComponent>


In real life example code runs well, browser does not show any errors, as well as Vite output...
If i remove the key, browser shows standard error about missing key when creating list of components.
In addition - I do have ESLint installed, as well as prettier.
My tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vite/client", "node"],

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "types"],

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

My .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/stylistic-type-checked',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: ['./tsconfig.json', './tsconfig.node.json'],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
    'react/no-unknown-property': ['error', { ignore: ['css', 'tw'] }],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['warn'],
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
  },
};



Ok, so I found the issue:
I am using Tailwind with Twin Macro in my project.
This forces type extension to be created:
file twin.d.ts
import 'twin.macro';
import styledImport, { CSSProp, css as cssImport } from 'styled-components';

declare module 'twin.macro' {
  // The styled and css imports
  const styled: typeof styledImport;
  const css: typeof cssImport;
}

declare module 'react' {
  // The css prop
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
    css?: CSSProp;
    tw?: string;
  }

  // The inline svg css prop
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  interface SVGProps<T> extends SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> {
    css?: CSSProp;
    tw?: string;
  }
}

//The 'as' prop on styled components
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
      as?: string | Element;
    }
  }
}

The issue was that
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
      as?: string | Element;
    }
  }
}

Should be written like that:
declare module 'react/jsx-runtime' {
  interface IntrinsicAttributes<T> extends React.DOMAttributes<T> {
    as?: string | Element;
  }
}

Everything is working fine!

This change worked well for us with an issue where key wasn't found on IntrinsicAttributes for whatever reason. Still getting errors where css prop can't be found, despite having the "correct" Twin configuration. We ported our project to use Turborepo with the same configs and dependencies, and TypeScript went haywire.
